# Python - Scrape Views Count from Instagram Video, load to JSON format

Tags: javascript, python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the number of views that specific videos on Instagram have. I'm relatively new to python but I'm guessing there must be a way given that the views can be found in the source code.

https://www.instagram.com/p/BOTU6rJhShv/ is one video I have been working with. As of this writing, it has 1759 views. Looking at the source code, 1759 is clearly listed as the "video_views" inside of a dictionary-like element:

[image: Total Views]

This element sits deep inside one of the page's  tag. From what I've read, the data is currently organized in a javascript form and should be converted to JSON to use in python. Here's what I have so far:

```
import json
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

page = urlopen('https://www.instagram.com/p/BOTU6rJhShv/')
soup = bs(page.read(),"html.parser")
body = soup.find('body',{'class':''})
script = body.find('script',{'type':'text/javascript'})
print(script)
```

Since I print the result of script at the bottom, I know this hones in on the section of the page I want to focus on. If I could read in that information to python, I can iterate through it find the "video_views" key, but that is where I am stuck. How can I convert the information between the script tags to JSON format and load into python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since the format is always the same, you could simply do this:

```
data = json.loads(script.text.replace('window._sharedData = ', '')[:-1])
```

**Update:** (I'm using python 2.7, so `urllib2.urlopen` is used instead)

I do get consistent output from this code:

```
import json
import re
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

page = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.instagram.com/p/BOTU6rJhShv/')
soup = bs(page.read(),"html.parser")
body = soup.find('body',{'class':''})
script = body.find('script',{'type':'text/javascript'})
data = json.loads(script.text.replace('window._sharedData = ', '')[:-1])
print data
print data['entry_data']['PostPage'][0]['media']['video_views']
```

Currently the `video_views` is 1759.

Comment: Check my update, I do get consistent results, may I know what different results yougot on your side?